# Restoring Original Font Size Keyboard Shortcuts After System Upgrade

Tags: keyboard, shortcut, font, zoom

My previous system-wide font size keyboard shortcuts were <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>+</kbd> for increasing, <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>-</kbd> for decreasing, and <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>0</kbd> for resetting to the default size. These shortcuts worked in both Chrome and iTerm.

After the latest system upgrade to Ventura 13.3 (22E252), the increase and decrease shortcuts have changed to <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>⇧</kbd><kbd>+</kbd> and <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>⇧</kbd><kbd>-</kbd>. Additionally, I can't find a shortcut for resetting the font size to default.

I couldn't locate these shortcuts in the keyboard shortcut menu or on the Apple support site.

**How can I restore the original keyboard shortcuts for font size adjustments?**

**Edit**: The problem was sovled after upgrading to Ventura 13.3.1 (22E261). It was probably caused by a bug in the previous version.

Comment: *"after the latest system upgrade, the increase and decrease shortcuts have changed"* ... upgrade to what - Ventura?

Comment: Have you tried going to System Settings > Keyboard > Keyboard Shortcuts > Decrease (or increase) font size and modifying the shortcut (click on it and enter the key combination you want)?

Comment: Yes, Vetura 13.3 (22E252). I tried changing the zoom settings, but it zooms the entire screen, not just the font size in the open window.

Answer (score 2):

Based on your previous keyboard shortcuts, i.e, <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd>, <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd>, and <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd> — it seems that you are looking for the 'zoom' shortcut, and not particularly 'font' increase/decrease.

If that is the case, you can create/change these shortcuts from:
System Settings > Keyboard > Shortcuts > App Shortcuts > All Applications

Where you should change/create the shortcut for:

> Zoom In     <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd> (corresponding to what you refer to as: "increasing")
> Zoom Out   <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd> (corresponding to what you refer to as: "decreasing")
> Actual Size   <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd> (corresponding to what you refer to as: "resetting the font size to default")

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks! For some reason, when I enter ⌘+ the system reads ⌘=. Any idea why?

Comment: Does it happen when you try to create the shortcut or when you try to use the shortcut?
What kind of keyboard do you have, i.e., language/region?
Do you have any keyboard customization or mapping?
Hard to say, could be any number or reasons. You'd have to provide much more information.

Comment: @AdamMatan cmd+ and cmd= does the same thing, it is described on an Apple Support article.

Comment: Oddly enough, it only works with cmd-shift-+, not with cmd-+.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I restore the original keyboard shortcuts for font size adjustments?

I don’t recommend this.  Since these  are Apple *systemwide*  shortcut definitions, developers will expect this and code accordingly.  They may use <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd> <kbd>+</kbd>/<kbd>-</kbd> for something else for example.

The keyboard shortcut <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>⌘ Command</kbd> <kbd>+</kbd>/<kbd>-</kbd> is defined as *Increase/Decrease the size of the selected item. Command–Equal sign (=) performs the same function as plus (+)*.  It’s not “Increase Font” or “Zoom”.

You can find these and more [keyboard shortcuts on the Apple site](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201236).  These specific shortcuts are at the bottom of the page.